# Data on US-production in each industry as defined per NAICS

Tags: data-request, usa, economics, industry

I am looking for data on economic production (as in GDP) split by industries.

So, for example, how much value did the car-manufacturing industry produce in 2016?

And this for all industries.

Ideally, industry categories should be as detailed as [6-digit NAICS codes](https://classcodes.com/naics-code-list/), but [3-digit NAICS code](https://classcodes.com/naics-3-digit-subsector-code-list/) would also be okay as long as I can get data for all industries.

Ideally, I am looking for 2016 data set, but can do with the 2015's in the absence of that.

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.bea.gov/iTable/iTable.cfm?ReqID=51&step=1#reqid=51&step=51&isuri=1&5114=q&5102=208), but more detailed ?

Comment: @Ettore Rizza: Exactly. I have found BEA data you linked shortly after I wrote the question and its structure is very similar to what I am looking for. Essentially, you can translate these BEA categories to two-digit NAICS levels which is a start but probably not detailed enough. I realized that six-digit NAICS data would probably be asking too much but three-digit NAICS seems like a reasonable level of detailedness and it should be available somewhere, I could not manage to find it (yet).

Answer (score 2):

You could try the Census Annual Survey of Manufacturers, County Business Patterns, or Statistics for U.S. Employer Firms. The advanced search function allows you to browse it based on NAICS code, and has three, four, and six-digit codes listed: https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/searchresults.xhtml?refresh=t

The Annual Survey specifically drills down to four-digit codes: https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/tableservices/jsf/pages/productview.xhtml?pid=ASM_2015_31AS101&prodType=table

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Following your tip, I have searched these data bases but have not found anything appropriate yet. I will keep searching, though, and will report back to the community when something interesting comes up.

Answer (score 2):

The BEA data for GDP by industry/sector is part of the National Income Products and Accounts (NIPA) tables and is the definitive source for this data. These GDP figures are calculations based on data collected by the Census Bureau including the Annual Survey of Manufacturers (ASM). The ASM data doesn't have a "GDP" field because it is showing data 1) as collected by a survey and 2) as extrapolated or estimated based on that survey.

For sizing industries, it is valid to use 2, 4, or 6 digit NAICS data from the ASM and looking at "Value of Shipments" or "Value of Product Shipments." These figures is not directly comparable to GDP figures, but they can be used to compare relative sizes of industries and to get an idea of approximate industry size.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Am I correct to assume that "value of shipments" is directly related to the export quota of each industry? Because if that's the case, comparing industries based on their "value of shipments" figures would be misleading, would it not? Or does shipments also include domestic shipment?

Comment: Shipments includes domestic and export shipments. The data come from companies filling out a Census form. The resulting data is easier to understand if you read the form itself, which for the 2015 survey is available at http://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/asm/technical-documentation/questionnaire/ma-10000-instructions-2015-final-12-8-15forbhs.pdf
See page 6 under "Item 5 - Sales, Shipments, Receipts, or Revenue"